# Binary representation of integers of powers of 2

Tags: c, types, binary

I'm having an issue interpreting the binary readout of numbers as stored in computer memory.

I wrote a small [program](https://github.com/snhilde/dtob) that takes an integer, floating point, or string and prints the binary number as stored in memory.

After this, I wanted to watch the play between decimal and binary. This led to an iteration of the powers of 2 from 0 to 64. To print the binary part, I used a section of the program above. What I found was strange to me, and I'm having trouble understanding why the system is storing the numbers as it is.

Here is my confusion:
For each iteration, the program is printing the decimal and binary version of 3 numbers, as such:

- 1 << i:
- 1 << i - 1:
- 1 << i (with all smaller bits set to 1 as well):

When the program reaches 30, here are the 6 outputs:

`30: 1073741824
30: 1073741823
30: 2147483647
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
11111111 11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

At 31, this happens:

`31: 18446744071562067968
31: 2147483647
31: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`

And this, at 32:

`32: 1
32: 0
32: 18446744073709551615
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`

## The Request

Could somebody please help me interpret these findings, including explaining why the bits do not continue to shift nicely until 18446744073709551615 (2 ^ 64 - 1) is reached?

(I would also welcome any suggestions on the program.)

### References

So you can play along at home, here is the program and the output that it gave me:

#### Reference Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void dtob(char *num, size_t size)
{
    int i;
    bool binary;

    for ( ; size; size--, num++) {
        for (i = 7; i > -1; i--) {
            binary = *num & (1 << i);
            printf("%d", binary);

        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    uintmax_t num1 = 0;
    uintmax_t num2 = 0;
    uintmax_t num3 = 0;

    void *ptr1;
    void *ptr2;
    void *ptr3;

    ptr1 = &num1;
    ptr2 = &num2;
    ptr3 = &num3;

    for (i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
        num1 = (1 << i);
        num2 = (1 << i) - 1;
        num3 |= (1 << i);

        printf("%d: %ju\n", i, num1);
        printf("%d: %ju\n", i, num2);
        printf("%d: %ju\n", i, num3);

        dtob(ptr1, sizeof(uintmax_t));
        dtob(ptr2, sizeof(uintmax_t));
        dtob(ptr3, sizeof(uintmax_t));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Reference Output:

```
0: 1
0: 0
0: 1
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
1: 2
1: 1
1: 3
00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
2: 4
2: 3
2: 7
00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
3: 8
3: 7
3: 15
00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
4: 16
4: 15
4: 31
00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
5: 32
5: 31
5: 63
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
6: 64
6: 63
6: 127
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
7: 128
7: 127
7: 255
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
8: 256
8: 255
8: 511
00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
9: 512
9: 511
9: 1023
00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
10: 1024
10: 1023
10: 2047
00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11: 2048
11: 2047
11: 4095
00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
12: 4096
12: 4095
12: 8191
00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
13: 8192
13: 8191
13: 16383
00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
14: 16384
14: 16383
14: 32767
00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
15: 32768
15: 32767
15: 65535
00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
16: 65536
16: 65535
16: 131071
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
17: 131072
17: 131071
17: 262143
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
18: 262144
18: 262143
18: 524287
00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
19: 524288
19: 524287
19: 1048575
00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
20: 1048576
20: 1048575
20: 2097151
00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
21: 2097152
21: 2097151
21: 4194303
00000000 00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
22: 4194304
22: 4194303
22: 8388607
00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
23: 8388608
23: 8388607
23: 16777215
00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
24: 16777216
24: 16777215
24: 33554431
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
25: 33554432
25: 33554431
25: 67108863
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
26: 67108864
26: 67108863
26: 134217727
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
27: 134217728
27: 134217727
27: 268435455
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
28: 268435456
28: 268435455
28: 536870911
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
29: 536870912
29: 536870911
29: 1073741823
00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
30: 1073741824
30: 1073741823
30: 2147483647
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
31: 18446744071562067968
31: 2147483647
31: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
32: 1
32: 0
32: 18446744073709551615
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
33: 2
33: 1
33: 18446744073709551615
00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
34: 4
34: 3
34: 18446744073709551615
00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
35: 8
35: 7
35: 18446744073709551615
00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
36: 16
36: 15
36: 18446744073709551615
00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
37: 32
37: 31
37: 18446744073709551615
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
38: 64
38: 63
38: 18446744073709551615
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
39: 128
39: 127
39: 18446744073709551615
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
40: 256
40: 255
40: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
41: 512
41: 511
41: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
42: 1024
42: 1023
42: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
43: 2048
43: 2047
43: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
44: 4096
44: 4095
44: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
45: 8192
45: 8191
45: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
46: 16384
46: 16383
46: 18446744073709551615
00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
47: 32768
47: 32767
47: 18446744073709551615
00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
48: 65536
48: 65535
48: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
49: 131072
49: 131071
49: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
50: 262144
50: 262143
50: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
51: 524288
51: 524287
51: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
52: 1048576
52: 1048575
52: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
53: 2097152
53: 2097151
53: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
54: 4194304
54: 4194303
54: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
55: 8388608
55: 8388607
55: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
56: 16777216
56: 16777215
56: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
57: 33554432
57: 33554431
57: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
58: 67108864
58: 67108863
58: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
59: 134217728
59: 134217727
59: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
60: 268435456
60: 268435455
60: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00001111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
61: 536870912
61: 536870911
61: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00011111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
62: 1073741824
62: 1073741823
62: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
63: 18446744071562067968
63: 2147483647
63: 18446744073709551615
00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
64: 1
64: 0
64: 18446744073709551615
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Thank you in advance!
Hilde

Comment: `1` has type `int`, and you also declare `i` to have type `int`, therefore the computation is performed according to that type and produces a result of that type.  On a present-day C implementation on a general-purpose computer, `int` is likely to be a 32-bit type, and your results are consistent with that.  Specifically, 2^31 is the smallest power of 2 that cannot be represented via a signed 32-bit type.

Comment: `num1 = (1 << i);` - `1` here is type `int`, and is probably 32 bits on your system.

Comment: Might help to read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: I'd suggest using types from `<stdint.h>` when you want types of a guaranteed size. Eg. `int64_t`. (The fixed-size types are optional by the standard but most implementations on most platforms provide them.)

Comment: John, that is exactly right. I typecast 1 as uintmax_t, and everything was solved. Will you change your comment to an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Thank you, John and Paul. That was exactly the help I needed.

Comment: @user3386109, that answered another question I was having. Thank you.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
        num1 = (1 << i);` is undefined behavior (UB), when `i==64`.  Also when `i== 63` and anytime `i` is wider than `int width`.

Answer (score 0):

Code is shifting outside allowable range.

```
uintmax_t num1;
for (i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
    num1 = (1 << i);         // int overflow! UB
```

If `int` is 32-bit, `1 << 31` is *undefined behavior*  (UB) shifting a 1 into the positive sign bit.

Using `1u` helps to avoid that in the `i==31` case.

Yet shifts like 32,33,34, ... when `unsigned` is 32-bit results in UB.

Use a wider `1` like `1LLU` which is at least 64 bits.

---

Code is still shifting outside allowable range.

```
uintmax_t num1;
for (i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
    num1 = (1LLU << i);  // trouble when i==64
```

If `unsigned long long` is 64-bit, `1LLU << 64` is UB.

Use a wider `1` like `UINTMAX_C(1)` *might* be wider than 64 bits, but not likely in 2018.

---

Moral of the story:

- Insure the integer math meets the target object's type.

  ```
  uintmax_t num1;
  num1 = UINTMAX_C(1) << i;
  // or     
  uintmax_t one = 1;
  num1 = one << i;
  // or when `num1` has a value
  num1 = (num1*0 + 1) << i;  // let the compiler optimize
  ```
- Do not shift wider than the type width.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for the examples and the well-formed answer. I appreciate your taking the time to fully explain a pretty simple problem.

Comment: So I can go off and learn more about it on my own, what is it called when you write ""1LLU" as opposed to "(unsigned long long)1"?

Comment: @HildeN Not much difference.  Consider `123456789012LU` vs.  `(unsigned long) 123456789012`.  The first is an unsigned constant that is at least as wide as `unsigned long`, but may be wider.  This is suitable for macro pre-processor math.   `(unsigned long) 123456789012` is an `unsigned long` even if 123456789012 is outside the `unsigned long` range - in which case, its value is not 123456789012.  Short story, `L` and `LL` insure a _minimum_ width type.  A cast forces the value to a particular type.  `U` make the value some unsigned type.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.